# Unable to attach an event handler to my control?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control

I'm working my way (slowly) through my first windows phone 7 app, and what I'm trying to do is attach the LoadCompleted event to a web browser control (so I can then invoke some javascript on the page to auto login to my helpdesk).

The problem is I can't figure out how to attach the event to my control. MSDN gives this code for the handler but I'm clueless:
public event LoadCompletedEventHandler LoadCompleted

Can someone help me out with the fix to my function below to make it work with the loadcompleted event?

```
    private void PageLoadCompleted(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e) 
    {
        if (e.Uri.ToString() == MainPage.HelpDeskUrl)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Page is loaded!");
            // invoke login code will go here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attaching load completed event handler to Windows application page can be done in two ways

Firstly by declaring loaded event handler function in page.xaml as below

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage 
    x:Class="Hubtile.AnimationPage" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">
```

Secondly by adding event handler for loaded event in page.xaml.cs constructor as specified below

```
Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Page_Loaded);
```

function `Page_Loaded` looks like as below

```
void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
     // add code  
     MessageBox.Show("Page is loaded!");
   }
```

Comment: You pointed me in the right direction, the routedeventargs didn't work however this did: webBrowser1.LoadCompleted += new System.Windows.Navigation.LoadCompletedEventHandler(Page_Loaded); private void Page_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e){}

Answer (score 0):

you can add the load completed event for web browser control in xaml as follows

handling function is as follows
private void myWebBrowser_LoadCompleted(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

or by adding event handler to the web browser control before calling navigate function. 
 myWebBrowser.LoadCompleted +=new LoadCompletedEventHandler(myWebBrowser_LoadCompleted);